# can we use load balancer on a two app services in azure

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a network with 2 app services, containing 2 slots each
I know the load balancers are designed to work with VM's, but I am wondering if it is possible to place a load balencer on these 2 app services to balance the load between them, Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Maybe you are looking for application gateway, it offers various layer 7 load balancing capabilities for your application.

Answer (score 11):

> but I am wondering if it is possible to place a load balencer on
>   these 2 app services to balance the load between them, Is it possible
>   to do so??

According to your description, maybe you are looking for Azure application gateway(layer 7).

Azure application gateway works at the application layer (Layer 7 in the OSI network reference stack). It acts as a **reverse-proxy service**, terminating the client connection and forwarding requests to back-end endpoints.

Azure application gateway support HTTP, HTTPS and Websockets.
[image]

Here is the **features** offered by each service:

[image]

More information about Application gateway, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe little late but I guess this what you are looking at

Scale Out- A scale out operation is the equivalent of creating multiple copies of your web site and adding a load balancer to distribute the demand  between them. When you scale out a web site in Windows Azure Web Sites there is no need to configure load balancing separately since this is already provided by the platform.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/scaling-up-and-scaling-out-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Scale-out is limited to 20 instances. See my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806432/915414

Comment: @Kenci That's not what the question was about, they need to load balance between 2 different app services, not instances.