# How to create a web application in a load balanced environment in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-appservice

Im new to using the load balancers on Azure , I need some advice , guidance on the following scenario.

I created and deployed a web app to my app service in Azure, thats all good. This web app can does some heavy processing and spawns a number of threads to do some transactions on a sql database.
Sometimes it gets very slow and the cpu usage climbs quite rapidly. There is also a logic app that runs a process every 2minutes.

Is there a way I can spawn up a load balancer for this web app so that it can distribute the load ?
Or is there a different process for app services ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we use load balancer on a two app services in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806326/can-we-use-load-balancer-on-a-two-app-services-in-azure)

Comment: sure does help , yes